# Have all images open in Magnific Popup, not just post images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering how to get Magnific Popup to work with all images and not just post images. I would specifically like this to work with images in the sidebar too.

This is the code I'm using in the footer widget of a Blogger blog:

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css' />
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
$('.post-entry').magnificPopup({
delegate:'a[imageanchor="1"]',
gallery: {
    enabled: true
},
  type: 'image'
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Would it apply to all images if I inserted it directly into the blog's template? If so, where?

You may have noticed that I'm not awesome at this? I know this is probably something basic, but it's still beyond me. I would appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add all the images in one div and call that div class in your javascript function 

<div class="popup-gallery">
<a href="placeholder"><img src="" width="75" height="75"></a>
<a href="placeholder"><img src="" width="75" height="75"></a>
<a href="placeholder"><img src="" width="75" height="75"></a>
<a href="placeholder"><img src="" width="75" height="75"></a>
</div>

Web Reference: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Or you can use FancyBox which is open source and easy to use
```